# Route Laravel (Not Found)

Tags: laravel

Good day,

I have problem to my **route** or to my **a href**

Once i try to click the href tag it gives me error

**www.siteexample/package**

Not Found
The requested URL /package was not found on this server.

This is my **HTACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you have error in your _routes/web.php_ file. b'coz your htaccess file have proper code. please check web.php once.

Comment: @hiteshmakodiya my route is correct, because all my routes is working to the localhost, however once i upload my project, all the assets,links are all not working.